# Start-up script runs under root and in the background

Tags: boot, bash, terminal

I'm trying to get a .sh script to run on system start-up. I've tried it several ways that don't work. The closest I got was using adding a line to `/home/pi/bashrc`

`sh /home/pi/Desktop/run.sh &`

This little script just starts up feh with a few parameters and restarts feh in case it crashes (which it does all the time but that's another issue).

The above runs `run.sh` but only under root and in the background. I can see that in the task manager.

What do I need to do to run run.sh under the pi user account and in the foreground? I'm puzzled.

Comment: *"adding a line to /home/pi/bashrc"* -> **Worst ever method** (for which I'm not blaming you, it seems to be an anti-pattern that has infected the Pi user community thanks I presume to blogs written by very unqualified people, and unfortunately, the same phenomenon here).  Don't use `.bashrc` this way, it will come back to bite you.  *It isn't run specifically at system boot*, it's run "When  an  interactive shell that is not a login shell is started" (`man bash`), which may (or may not) happen at boot, but is likely to include other events as well.

Comment: Yes, I experienced that first hand! Ain't no good. Amazing how that's repeated everywhere, often enough so I couldn't find a correct answer by bingoogling.

Answer (score 2):

To run the script in the foreground as PI user on startup, type the following commands in terminal to create a file `run.desktop` in `~/.config/autostart`

```
cd ~/.config/autostart

nano run.desktop
```

Now, paste the following code in run.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=lxterminal -e "/home/pi/Desktop/run.sh"
Type=Application
```

Save the file by pressing CTRL + O and then CTRL + X.

Comment: Good answer, but you don't need to include the `nano` usage stuff, it's at best clutter and at worst confusing.   It's pretty obvious from the question the OP is capable of creating and editing text files on the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It didn't work at first (it just brings up the terminal, the calls inside `run.sh` are not executed, I cannot even see them in the task manager. The terminal window is entirely blank). However, when I changed the `Exec` line to `bash -c "sh /home/pi/Desktop/run.sh"` it worked! --- Any insights to why this worked for me and not the `lxterminal -e` command?

Comment: Perhaps if the script did not have a shebang and/or was not marked executable?